# When and how is generated the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

I read the following tutorial

- [How to use ssh-keyscan on Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/ssh-keyscan-ubuntu)

I confirmed that `ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X` scan and prints **all** *the public keys* values of the server/host - that output comes from the following files from the server/host

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

I can **filter** them through the `-t` option such as:

- `ssh-keyscan -t key_type 192.168.1.X`

Where `key_type` can be `rsa`, `ecdsa` and `ed25519` and even mixed such as: `rsa,ecdsa`

For example:

- `ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.1.X`

Until here I understand all these 2 variations of the command. I confirmed that behavior in my PC

Now, the reason of this post, after to do a research of this command - according with:

- [ssh-keyscan(1) - from man.openbsd.org](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan)
- [ssh-keyscan(1) - from linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keyscan)

Both do mention of the `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file, exists the

> If an `ssh_known_hosts` file is constructed using `ssh-keyscan` without
> verifying the keys, users will be vulnerable to man in the middle
> attacks. On the other hand, if the security model allows such a risk,
> `ssh-keyscan` can help in the detection of tampered keyfiles or man in
> the middle attacks which have begun after the `ssh_known_hosts` file was
> created

is not clear if the `ssh_known_hosts` is *created/constructed* automatically or using some option, such as `-c` for example - I know that option does not exist.

Well that file does not exist in the client - I assumed that after of the command executions that file should be generated or created automatically - that path and file name exists for some explicit reason, right? - something similar how the `.ssh/known_hosts` file is created/updated when the `ssh username@hostname` command is used and is accepted the server's fingerprint by the client

Comment: Nit: `ssh-keyscan` asks for, and gets if available, all keytypes _other than DSA_. This was true even before OpenSSH 7.0 up disabled _use_ of DSA on connections by default. See https://serverfault.com/questions/1075224/ssh-keyscan-to-known-hosts-produces-no-results .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` normally does not exist in a typical installation.  It exists specifically to provide a way to provide an equivalent to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` that works for all users for a system.  It isn't updated automatically because (a) most users will not have privileges to modify it and (b) just because one random user approves a key does not mean that that decision should apply to the entire system.

For example, at my work, this file is generated automatically such that every internal host's SSH key is provided so that users can log into hosts as needed without being prompted for keys.  This is done by a trusted automated process that gathers the data when each server is provisioned.

The warning is essentially just telling you that all `ssh-keyscan` does is tell you what keys you get when you scan that server, not whether those keys are the correct, trusted keys for that server.  For example, if you have a machine on your network that intercepts all connections to port 22, doing an `ssh-keyscan github.com` will give you the keys for the intercepting machine, not the real keys for GitHub.  To know whether the keys are legitimate, you need some sort of out-of-band information, which could be a human-to-human communication, an email, a web page, or an SSHFP record validated with DNSSEC.

Comment: Thank you - BTW, apart and just for clarification, If I am correct according with your explanation: the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is for each user (`/home/xxx`) with its own values isolated of the rest and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is for global or for all the user to be shared. If I am correct, consider to add a special note, because many tutorials on the web use both files, but is not clear when use each one. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Just being curious, in your answer: first it gives the impression that is created/updated is manually (_It isn't updated automatically because ..._), but later that is automatic (_For example, at my work, this file is generated automatically ..._). In many tutorials I saw mostly is manually - i.e: `ssh-keyscan 172.19.144.16 >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

Comment: It is not done automatically unless you create a process which does so.  My work does that, but OpenSSH does not do that on anyone's behalf.

Comment: FYI, you need to set `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` in /etc/ssh/ssh_config to have the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts checked.  but AFAIK a user can simply overwrite this setting with ssh -o ... rendering the global setting somewhat useless.